# Разместить блок за границей страницы

Tags: html, css

Хочу отодвинуть картинку, как показано на картинке ниже[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но появляется нижний скролл, подскажите как можно его исправить, для картинки и родителя прописаны следующие стили:

```
.top__image {
    width: 523px;
    height: auto;
    transform: translateX(141%);
    position: absolute;
}
.top__image-img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: контейнер(элемент фона + картинка + элемент после картинки). Зачем что-то двигать? Контейнер имеет свой основной размер, например, 500, первый элемент 100, картинка на всю ширину 500 или 400, последний элемент 50. И уже потом, в самом конце, на контейнер применить overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `overflow: hidden;` (в данном случае - `overflow-x`) для `body`, чтобы убрать полосы прокрутки.

*Значения высоты и ширины я установил только для  примера. Значение `translateX` установил из вопроса.*

Сравните:

***Без `overflow: hidden;`***

```css
body {
}

#parent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 523px;
    height: 523px;
    transform: translateX(141%);
    background: #0f0;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='parent'>
        <div id='child'>
            Ребёнок
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

***С `overflow: hidden;`***

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#parent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 523px;
    height: 523px;
    transform: translateX(141%);
    background: #0f0;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='parent'>
        <div id='child'>
            Ребёнок
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```